# insert not working on mysql 5.7.12-0?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-error-1064

my table structure is

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emp` (
 `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `age` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

My query is :

```
 INSERT INTO `emp` (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('1', 'prashant');
```

This is working with all the MYSQL versions below 5.7, but not working with MYSQL version  **5.7.12-0ubuntu1**

Getting error :

```
#1364 - Field 'age' doesn't have a default value
```

What is new in this version ??

**Try it on mysql version below 5.7 ,you will see the difference.**

Thanks :-)

Comment: `Age` is defined as `NOT NULL`, but you aren't specifying a value for it in your `INSERT` statement.  You either need to 1) set a `DEFAULT` value for it, or 2) add it to the `INSERT` statement.  In addition to the missing `age` value, you're also attempting to `INSERT` an `id` value, which is defined as `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  (Also, unrelated to your error, but `age` being defined as a `VARCHAR(31)` is just weird...)

Comment: @Siyual it is working in all mysql version below 5.7 , try once on your machine :-)

Comment: I know of no version of MySQL that allows you to insert a `NULL` into a field declared as `NOT NULL`.

Comment: There is literally **no way** that this query can work with ANY MySQL version. You're 100% not showing us the entire code.

Comment: @Mjh please try it once on mysql version 5.7 :-)

Comment: @PrashantSharma - I don't have to try anything. Your field is defined as `NOT NULL`, has NO default value and you are not supplying any value for it. Every MySQL version will yield an error if you try to insert into a table and if you don't specify the value for such a field. Reason that it might work for you for other versions is that you probably have a trigger that supplies a value for that field, thus you think it works. Hence, I stand by my statement that this isn't your actual code that's giving you issues.

Comment: You are probably having strict mode off in your previous installation. That's the only way you will be able to do what you say you have done

Comment: @e4c5 yes you are right,I was not aware of it

Comment: May I impose upon you to mark the answer as correct so that it may help others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a huge surprise if this worked in any version of mysql at all. Copy paste this into [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) (mysql 5.6 or 5.5) and confirm for yourself.

`age` is defined as `varchar(31)` and not null. Thus your insert statement should have a value for that column. Or you should give it a default value. While you are at it, change it to a more appropriate data type.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emp` (
 `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `age` int(3) NOT NULL default 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

**Updated:**

Thinking about this some more I think you have switched off [Strict Mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) in your older version of mysql

> Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in
>   data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE. A value can be
>   invalid for several reasons. For example, it might have the wrong data
>   type for the column, or it might be out of range. A value is missing
>   when a new row to be inserted does not contain a value for a non-NULL
>   column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause in its definition. (For a
>   NULL column, NULL is inserted if the value is missing.) Strict mode
>   also affects DDL statements such as CREATE TABLE.

So my original statement is wrong! With string mode off, the default for varchar is probably '' (not sure though never used strict mode off)

Comment: Interesting point about strict mode, I'll keep that one in mind from now on. +1 from me for the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

In your table age described as `not null`.

```
`age` varchar(31) NOT NULL
```

So, it is required field for insert.

Comment: which version of mysql are u using ?

Comment: This is no matter of version.

Answer (score 0):

The `NOT NULL` constraint enforces a field to always contain a value. This means that you cannot insert a new record, or update a record without adding a value to this field.You have to give value for age also in your `insert` query because it cannot be `null`.For eg:-

```
insert into emp(`id`,`name`,`age`) values('1','rahul','26')
```

hope this helps!!.Comment for further query