# SQL error: 1364 Field 'XXXX' doesn't have a default value1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table ROUTE

```
CREATE TABLE ROUTE (
RouteID INTEGER(4) AUTO_INCREMENT,
RouteName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
BoardingStop VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
AlightingStop VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (RouteID )
);
```

And a second table CUSTOMER

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CustomerID INTEGER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CustomerAge VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Address VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
RouteID INTEGER(4) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (RouteID) REFERENCES ROUTE(RouteID)
);
```

When I insert data into customerID

```
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER` (`CustomerID`,`CustomerName`,`CustomerAge`,`Address`) VALUES (1,"Madeline Shepard",17,"Ap #303-5324 Nunc St.");
```

I get t he following error

> Error Code: 1364. Field 'RouteID' doesn't have a default value

Help

How do I fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insert not working on mysql 5.7.12-0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374536/insert-not-working-on-mysql-5-7-12-0)

Comment: You're in the wrong database, or in the wrong schema.

Comment: I can't see a column teachers_id_teacher but maybe the issue is you are not specifying a value for RouteID and this is not null, and has no default?

Comment: The field 'teachers_id_teacher' is not listed in your question? Please provide full information. 
Also the insert statement will require an id for the field RouteID as this field is set as 'NOT NULL'.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where `teachers_id_teacher` is coming from, however the error text does seem accurate in regards to the insert statement you've provided.

Your field `RouteID` is "required" (as indicated by `NOT NULL`), yet you've omitted it from your `INSERT`.

Because you haven't provided a value and it doesn't have a default, the insert will fail. Either set a default value for this field, or specify a value:

```
INSERT INTO `CUSTOMER` (`CustomerID`,`CustomerName`,`CustomerAge`,`Address`, `RouteID`) VALUES (1,"Madeline Shepard",17,"Ap #303-5324 Nunc St.", 1234);
```